# How to trigger a http azure function from another azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have written a HTTP trigger azure function that executes a series of operations (like add files to blob storage, list them, delete them or do some more time requiring tasks through orchestrator), according to [Azure Durable Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode?tabs=windows%2Cazure-cli-set-indexing-flag&pivots=python-mode-configuration).

I want to retrieve the status of such time requiring tasks through an additional azure function that, based on the job id of the orchestrator, returns "Pending", "Completed" or "Failed". In order to do that, I need to make a request inside the main HTTP trigger function to ask for such status.

I've tried:

- azure functions [http.HttpRequest(url)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.http.httprequest?view=azure-python) and [HttpRequest(url)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httprequest?view=azure-python)
- requests.get(url)

Neither of them apparently works locally, since Visual Studio Code in debug mode completely freezes. Can it be due to authorization issues or is it not possible to trigger another azure function locally? Will it work once I deploy the code?

I've read the suggested articles in stackoverflow and the relative azure functions documentation, but none of them is providing a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

> How to trigger a http azure function from another azure function

In **C#** you can call using `httpClient` as below:

```
var r = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:7114/api/Function1");
var c = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

[image]

Output of both functions:

Function which is called from Another function(Function 1 should start executing like below:
[image]

Then when I run function 2 and this is function1 logs:

[image]

For further you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76096260/can-i-call-an-azure-fuction-from-a-api-controller-using-net-6/76097882#76097882).

**For python in VS CODE:**

In Visual Studio defaultly, different Projects run on different ports where as  In VS code same port is used and you will get this error:

[image]

Deploy to Portal:
[image]

Then get the URL like below:

[image]

For that you need to deploy your function first to azure and then get the `URL` and make it working like below:

```
u='https://rith34.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=jd5WmzFuRxdyTg=='

requests.post(u)
```

[image]

requirements.txt:

[image]

Output in Portal:

Check the deployed function monitor section:

[image]

For further refer similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071284/calling-a-http-trigger-logic-app-post-call-with-an-azure-function-python/74121447#74121447).